# Aptana Studio 3 - text font size minimizing with Ctrl + -

Tags: preferences, aptana3

hello I have recently installed aptana studio 3 again and I am having where my text font size minimizes when I do the command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>). I am talking about the font under `General->Appearance->Colors` and `Fonts->Basic->Text Font`. This command works like in photoshop/illustrator where the size minimizes. However I do not want this command because I usually press it on accident. I have looked under keys and I can't find this command so I can change it. It wouldn't be so bad but the command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> doesn't upsize the font like it normally does in other applications. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

Try holding down your shift key: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Aptana Studio 3 has a problem with shortcuts.
I accidentally zoomed out my code and as I'm in Portuguese Keyboard, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> didn't work to back to the default zoom value.

The solution to this problem *(probably many other keyboard set's are having this problem)* is to change your **language preferences** (<kbd>Win Key</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd> OR find it in <kbd>Control Panel</kbd>), to English keyboard.

Then with the help of [**this image**](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/9c/ISO_keyboard_%28105%29_QWERTY_UK.svg/750px-ISO_keyboard_%28105%29_QWERTY_UK.svg.png), I find the <kbd>+</kbd> is the first key to left of the <kbd>backspace</kbd>.

This way you could go back to 100% zoom by hitting, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> (first key to left of the <kbd>backspace</kbd>)

Very strange situation ...

Answer (score 1):

Select the whole page you are writing the code.click on the right button of the mouse. click preference.In the above of the window, there are a link named "Colors and Fonts",click here.click edit.